# Digital Signature verfication,The selected certificate has errors not valid for usage

Tags: java, digital-signature

Invalid Signature Error when trying to validate signed PDF?

Comment: And what is your question? And where did you provide the PDF for analysis?

Comment: here is pdf file link for analysis.plese use "clr"  as  password to open the pdf :https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=449a4623ebec694c&id=449A4623EBEC694C!114&mkt=en-US

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The certificate needs to be signed by a CA (not self-signed) or Acrobat will display the "There are problems with this signature" message. You can solve this problem locally for your computer (although other computers will still see the warning) by temporarily adding the certificate to your trusted store (however, be sure to remove it after testing: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36913/adding-self-signed-certificate-to-trusted-store).

Answer (score 3):

*In short*

The certificate whose associated private key has been used for signing your PDF, has a **Key Usage** entry indicating that it is not meant for signing documents but for enciphering private or secret keys, i.e., for key transport.

Please use a private key and certificate generated for document signing

*In detail*

Your certificate has

```
1088   14:         SEQUENCE {
1090    3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER keyUsage (2 5 29 15)
1095    1:           BOOLEAN TRUE
1098    4:           OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
1100    2:             BIT STRING 5 unused bits
         :               '100'B (bit 2)
         :             }
         :           }
```

[RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) defines:

```
  KeyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
       digitalSignature        (0),
       nonRepudiation          (1), -- recent editions of X.509 have
                            -- renamed this bit to contentCommitment
       keyEncipherment         (2),
       dataEncipherment        (3),
       keyAgreement            (4),
       keyCertSign             (5),
       cRLSign                 (6),
       encipherOnly            (7),
       decipherOnly            (8) }

...

  The keyEncipherment bit is asserted when the subject public key is
  used for enciphering private or secret keys, i.e., for key
  transport.  For example, this bit shall be set when an RSA public
  key is to be used for encrypting a symmetric content-decryption
  key or an asymmetric private key.
```